# Emberjs site size issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ember.js, single-page-application

I have created app using emberjs file, but my app.js file is more 3.2 MB after build which take time to load and site is becoming slow. Can you please suggest how I can decrease size of site ?

I am also thinking to move the code to Reactjs. So please suggest what should I do.

Comment: Instead of one single large app, one approach is to have separate single page apps for different modules / sections of your site to keep it smaller.  Have the shared code cached and only downloaded once, and the app specific parts split up by module.  Also what are you using to minify your code?  And are you compressing it on your server?  That can also help.

Comment: Try to make use of `loading` sub-states in ember. 3.2mb sounds like a lot, but it's not really that big.. there are strategies to deliver the app, which you might want to look into, like cdn for example

Comment: @NicholasSmith I am minifying and compressing the app.js on server. Also caching all js and css files.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe What are other strategies to deliver the emberjs app? Also how about using reacjs ?

Comment: @Amita CDN for example, could be part of your delivery strategy.. and remember, that 3.2 meg is gonna be downloaded once.. after that it should use cached bits and only download data/content until the app gets updated/deployed

Comment: Not Emberjs specific, but a common strategy is to split up your js into separate builds.  Maybe based on user type, if certain types of users can only access specific parts of the site you can serve them a smaller app.js specific to their role.

Comment: server side rendering could be an another solution. See: [ember-fastboot](https://ember-fastboot.com/)

Comment: Do you use `ember-cli`? And you'r talking about your `applicationname.js`, not your `vendor.js`? Because the ember build pipeline creates massive smaller output files when using the production environment. Also the `applicationname.js` only includes addons and your code, so are you actually writing 3.2 MB code? what addons are you using? Ember is [not that large](http://iao.fi/ember-size/). So just `ember` + `ember-data` is about 1MB, unzipped. Also do you know about `ember-engines`?